# How to retrieve a row where value is taken from other row in a same table (MYSQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok, I have this table

```
ControlID - Version - Type - Rel ID  - Parent Rel ID
1         - 2       - 11   - 212     - 5
1         - 2       - 44   - 542     - 5
1         - 2       - 47   - 742     - 5

2         - 2       - 11   - 200     - 4
2         - 2       - 14   - 565     - 4
2         - 2       - 20   - 700     - 4
```

As showed in the above table, we have data in 2 blocks (Note: **Rel ID is unique**):

Block 1

```
ControlID - Version - Type - RelID  - ParentRelID
1         - 2       - 11   - 212     - 5
1         - 2       - 44   - 542     - 5
1         - 2       - 47   - 742     - 5
```

Block 2

```
ControlID - Version - Type - RelID  - ParentRelID
2         - 2       - 11   - 200     - 4
2         - 2       - 14   - 565     - 4
2         - 2       - 20   - 700     - 4
```

Ok, now user will enter any relID & the system will show the the `Rel ID` that has type=11 in the same block of entered relID.

Ex: if user enters `700`, then it will know that `700` belongs to block 2 & then it will search the type=11 in block 2 & print out `200`

Ex2: if user enters `742`, then it will know that `742` belongs to block 1 & then it will search the type=11 in block 1 & print out `212`

This is my query but I think it is too long & may be slow.

```
Select relID from mytable where  controlID = (select controlID from mytable where relID=700) 
and 
version= (select version from mytable where relID=700) 
and parentRelID= (select parentRelID from mytable where relID=700) 
and type=11
```

The above query works but too long & maybe slow, can you make it shorter & make it run faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you also selecting on `version` and `ParentRelId` ??  Do they also determine the Block?  i.e., can there be different blocks that have the same `RelID` but have different `version`s and/or different `parentRelID`s ?

If not, try this:

```
Select * From table t
Where type = 11
   And ControlId =
        (Select ControlId 
         From table
         Where RelId = @RelId)
```

or ....

```
Select * From table t
Where type = 11
    and exists (Select * from table
                Where relId = @RelId
                  and ControlId = t.ControlId)
```

Comment: ControlId can be repeated in other block say block3 for example

Comment: the 2nd query is running faster than the 1st query?

Comment: If `controlId` can be repeated in another "Block", then what defines a "Block"?  If it's not `ControlId`, then these queries I provided will not work in those scenarios.  As to performance differences, Look at query plans to see why...

Comment: just include other field in the list and exists (Select * from table
                Where relId = @RelId
                  and ControlId = t.ControlId and version=t.version and parentRelID=t.parentRelID)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.RelId FROM table t1
    INNER JOIN table t2
    ON t1.ControlId = t2.ControlId
WHERE t2.RelId = 700
AND t1.type = 11
```